# Magento 2.1.4: show custom shipping method only for register/logged in user

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1.4

I have a custom shipping module and it works fine.

Now I want to show it only in the checkout if the customer/user is logged in/registered.

Is there any file where I can make a function to check this?

The only file I know is the shipping.html but this couldn't be the right one because it's a js generated file.